# Ajax request failing only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

The following Ajax call fails only in IE. I have already tried setting the cache to false and setting the contentType. The call always results in the error function in IE.

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        cache: false,
        url: 'http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location='+address+'&flags=J&appid=dj0yJmk9Y1VON011hMQ',
        dataType:'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
         var quality = parseInt(data.ResultSet.Quality);
         if(quality > 50){                   
             var result = data.ResultSet.Results[0];
             if(result.line1 == streetString && result.city == cityString && result.statecode == stateString && result.uzip == zipString)
                 form.submit();
             else if(result.line1 == ""){
                 $(errorElement).html("Could not find street");
                 $(form).find("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled"); 
             }                  
             else{      
                    var foundAddress = "....Found Address Text...."                                     
                    addressDialog.dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        width:400,
                        resizable:false,
                        title: "Confirm Address",
                        buttons:[
                             {
                                 text:"Confirm",
                                 click:function(){
                                    street.val(result.line1);
                                    city.val(result.city);
                                    state.val(result.statecode);
                                    zip.val(result.uzip);
                                    form.submit();
                                 }
                             },
                             {
                                 text:"Cancel",
                                 click:function(){
                                     addressDialog.dialog("close");
                                 }
                             }
                        ],
                        close:function(event,ui){
                            $(form).find("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled"); 
                        }                       
                    });
                    addressDialog.dialog("open");
             }       
         }else{
             $(form).find("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");
             $(errorElement).html("Invalid Address");
         }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert(jqXHR.status);
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
      });
```

errorElement is just a span which i print the error out too.

When i specify the dataType as "json" alerts come out as

0 , error , No Transport

When i change it to "jsonp" alerts show

200,parseerror, Error:jquery1720949182345742317_1351868503283 was not called

Comment: Could you show us the success function? My guess is you are using Json.parse in an older version of IE in which it is not supported.

Comment: replace alert("Error") with alerts that alert each of the three arguments. "Error" isn't very informative.

Comment: Do you need to be using dataType:'jsonp' here because you are accessing an external URL?